# How to configure Windows/Linux to support absolute-mouse-mode for remote operation via KVM?

Tags: linux, windows, drivers, mouse

I am working on a project where we want to connect different dual-screen PC systems (mostly Windows+Linux) with a dualhead KVM switch. The KVM switch uses absolute mouse mode to position the mouse on the target system.

**Windows:**
For many Windows systems this works well for the 1st screen, but doesn't work for the 2nd screen.
This fits to information I found that Microsoft restricted the absolute mouse mode to the 1st screen after a security update [KB5003637](https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/topic/8-juni-2021-kb5003637-betriebssystembuilds-19041-1052-19042-1052-und-19043-1052-fd782405-7736-478e-b8d0-b08f735f7e54)
There seem to be special KVM mouse drivers that allow to get the absolute mouse functionality back for all connected screens, e.g. from Matrox: [Matrox KVM mouse driver](https://video.matrox.com/en/apps/drivers/graphics/download?id=816)

**Linux:**
For Linux systems I currently don't understand if Linux supports absolute mouse mode and how I can find out if the target system is in general compatible (does it depend on the Linux kernel?) and how to configure it correctly so that the USB device that the KVM switch introduces will actually be working with a mouse driver that supports absolute mouse mode.

My questions would be:

- I the information about the Windows restrictions is correct?
- Is there another way to get the functionality back to Windows? Can I roll back the security update or recover the old Microsoft mouse driver?
- What is the actual situation for Linux and how to get around possible restrictions here?

Thanks a lot for your help!

J.